# Get table row count in watir

Tags: watir

How to get the table row count in Watir.

I tried [row_count](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Table#row_count-instance_method) function like this but it gives an error.

```
table = $browser.table(:id,"student_list")
table.row_count()
```

This gives the following error.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `row_count' for < #Watir::Table:0x000000034ee2f8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line

```
puts $browser.table(:id,"student_list").rows.count
```

Or

```
puts $browser.table(:id,"student_list").rows.length
```